# How to convert equations to dictionary?

Tags: python

Is there any way to convert equations(not defined, these are strings) to dictionaries? For example:

```
abc=a*b*c
efg=e*f*g
```

to be:

```
{‘ abc’:[a,b,c],’ efg’:[e,f,g]}
```

I have thousands of equations. Is it possible to build a loop?

Comment: Are those string equations in their own string-type variables, or in a list, or? This is totally possible to just `split()` the string on `=` and set the first element to the key and the second element to the value.

Comment: What do you imagine are the logical steps to solve the problem? Where do you get stuck when you try to write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
inp = '''
abc=a*b*c
efg=e*f*g
'''

dct = {}
for st in inp.split('\n')[1:-1]:
    key, val = st.split('=')
    dct[key] = val.split('*')
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'abc': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'efg': ['e', 'f', 'g']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eqns = []
eqns.append("abc=a*b*c")
eqns.append("efg=e*f*g")

eqns_dict = {}

for eqn in eqns:
    left, right = eqn.split("=")
    eqns_dict[left] = right.split("*")
```